# Get list of key-value pairs of APCU

Tags: php, apc, apcu

I'm trying to get a list of the key-value stored in APCu.

I have tried apcu_cache_info(), but it doesn't return the value and returns a lot of additional info that I don't need. I don't know if APCUIterator can be the solution, I'm trying to understand the syntax... I have tried the documentation example but nothing happens:

```
foreach (new APCUIterator('/^counter\./') as $counter) {
    echo "$counter[key]: $counter[value]\n";
    apc_dec($counter['key'], $counter['value']);
}
```

Some hint?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is the format of the keys that you use for the cache?

Comment: Dynamically generated strings

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (new APCUIterator('/^\.*/') as $counter)
{
    echo "$counter[key] ---> $counter[value] \n";
}
```